# Can I get stable signed ids with #to_signed_global_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I call:

```rb
Appointment.last.to_signed_global_id.to_s
# => BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6Bk...27c1175e6e2
Appointment.last.to_signed_global_id.to_s
# => BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVU....0efc706151feed7178
```

Is there a way to always return the same signed global id?

Comment: The point of signing the ID is that you're generating a Base64 string. https://github.com/rails/globalid/blob/6cdb13f9f5c526498d281b1079c5dcae0f87fcd8/lib/global_id/verifier.rb

Comment: `GlobalID::Locator.locate_signed(Appointment.last.to_signed_global_id.to_s)` should always find the expected record, so why do you need to "stabilize" the Base64?

Comment: @Chiperific i use the generated in my tests and need to check that the redirected url for instance is correct

Comment: So can you just save the object instead of the string? What happens if you just drop the `.to_s` off your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get signed global ids. It's not stable because by default, there is an expiration of [1 month in Rails](https://github.com/rails/globalid#signed-global-ids).

To make your signed global ID stable, set the expiration to nil.

```rb
Appointment.last.to_signed_global_id(expires_in: nil).to_s
```

Calling the above code any number of times will now always generate the same string result, unless you change the signing key.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand your use case, but the short answer to your title is: yes, by default calling `#to_signed_global_id` on a record is stable

I think your issue is turning the signed ID into a string: `.to_s`.

From one of my apps:

```
2.7.0 :002 > one = Element.first.to_sgid
  Element Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "elements".* FROM "elements" ORDER BY "elements"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2.7.0 :003 > two = Element.first.to_sgid
  Element Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "elements".* FROM "elements" ORDER BY "elements"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2.7.0 :004 > one == two
 => true 
2.7.0 :005 > one.to_s == two.to_s
 => false
```

I can create two SignedGlobalID variables from the same record and they match each other, but once I force them to be strings, the Base64s differ as expected.

Comment: I'm using `to_s` because I'm generating the url of a model in my test and comparing that to the url that an action redirects to, but there are different

Comment: So then the answer is simply 'no', the `.to_s` won't match Object comparison

Comment: "to_sgid" - has expiration date set by Rails. It can be overwritten globally or per record.